# Slide links turned into not working hyperlinks. How to turn the hyperlinks back to slide links or make the hyperlinks work?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink, links, slideshow

A Powerpoint presentation from 2009 that has working slide links was saved as a new file, in the same format "Microsoft PowerPoint 97-2003-Präsentation (.ppt)", and the slide links have turned into not working hyperlinks. Therefore, it was not just a change of the PowerPoint Version that triggered this.

#### Tried

The problem remains if it is saved as a "Microsoft PowerPoint-Präsentation (.pptx)".

#### Example:

##### Before (working)

If you hover over the link, you see popping up:

[image]
("Folie 2")

And if you right click to edit the link, you see:
[image]

The slide link points at `2. Folie 2`

##### After (not working)

If you hover over the link, you see popping up:

[image]
("#Folie 2")

And if you right click to edit the link, you see:

[image]

The hyperlink address is `%23Folie202`.

The master slide looks as follows:

[image]

#### Question

Why have the slide links become hyperlinks? How to turn this back or make the hyperlinks work?

Comment: For the first image, could you replace it by the whole dialog, same as in the second one?

Comment: @harrymc You mean I should put the text in the screenshots in English, so that it is searchable?

Comment: No, just give the whole dialog.

Comment: @harrymc I do not understand. I already show the whole dialog, I guess. Perhaps I do not know what you mean with dialog then. I think you mean the menu when you hover over the link or edit the link. Right?

Comment: I don't know WHY it's happened but the link has somehow gotten a # character in front of it. That tells PowerPoint to look for the slide in a different file rather than in the current file, but there's nothing in the link to tell it WHAT file. Sometimes this kind of thing can be caused by unexpected characters in the slide TITLE placeholder.  What's in the title placeholders on your slides?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I may not share the title slide but I can tell that it shows links to all of the slides. I guess that it happens if you save the file to another folder than the one that it is in, say, on the Desktop or a stick, perhaps also on a newer Windows. Then, the file might "think" that the path has changed, and this might trigger the links to become hyperlinks if the path is added only as a dummy, like with "#". But that cannot be the whole truth. If I take the original file, which is still working, and work it over again, I can also save it elsewhere. This fixed it, but it costs time.

Comment: Saving a file with internal links to another folder won't change anything. But you mention " if the path is added only as a dummy, like with "#" ... ""  Did you add a # character to the path as a dummy/placeholder when creating the links?  # in a hyperlink has a special meaning in PPT

Comment: @SteveRindsberg No, I did not do anything with the links. Never looked into that stuff at all, the whole presentation came with the working slide links, and I later just changed the text of some slides. The working slide links just became #-hyperlinks out of nowhere. It stopped working after changing the text in some slides and saving and/or moving it.

Comment: >> "and I later just changed the text of some slides"  The title placeholder text, possibly? And if so, from what to what?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I went through all of the slides, checking all text boxes. There is nothing strange in any format. It is all just text, and the few things that were changed are also just plain text. There is one little strange thing in one slide: a picture is put at the bottom of a slide although it should be in the middle. But that is just a mistake of someone pasting it without moving it afterwards or so.

Comment: At this point, I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid, unless you can share a simple version of a couple of the slides, one set before the changes happened, one after. With any sensitive/proprietary information removed, of course.